# hover button background color remains on mobile

Tags: css, iphone

I styled a button:

```
.subscribe_button {
   background-color: red;
}

.subscribe_button:hover { 
   background-color: black;
}
```

When I hover over the button, it turns black. However, on mobile, the background color of the button remains black even after hover. So I hover over the button, it turns black and remains black  How do I prevent it from remaining black after hover?

Comment: You have a typo, you used an underscore in one class name and a hyphen in the other.

Comment: What? Hover on mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***begin EDIT*** by S3C on 2019-12-03

This solution should work, if all is set properly. But I just stumbled upon a case of code-salad (a very unorganized bunch of CSS files in different directories, same styling rules are being overwritten way too many times, lots of `!important`s, etc.). We were on a tight budget and it had to be finished very quickly.

In this case I needed this solution in navigation where all navigation links are in `<li>` tags for desktop version of the site, and in `<button>` or `<div>` tags (styled with bootstrap `class="btn"`) for mobile version of the site.

The following CSS was the one that overwrote all others with the "same" instructions and made the browser present those buttons green instead of white after being clicked on in mobile mode:

```css
.pre-header .container .row .btn a:hover {
    color: #205c1b !important;
}
```

So I just overwrote it again for mobile only (just beneath the previous code) with:

```css
@media(max-width: 600px) {
    .pre-header .container .row .btn a:hover {
        color: #fff !important;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** You shouldn't do things this way! But it does work, if you're being time pressured.

***end EDIT***

***begin ORIGINAL POST*** by S3C on 2019-03-22

I was looking for a solution to this very same problem.

In my case I have a navigation made with bootstrap classes. All direct links are divs and all parents of dropdown menus are buttons with exact same styling.

When mouse is available, you would want hover to change text color, so user knows it's a clickable link. On touchscreens though you don't want that color change, since as you have figured out it won't go away after click.

Do not despair, **there IS a solution**.

[Jacque Goupil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813263/jacque-goupil)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275891/9583480) gives us a clue.

He stated that

> Most mobile browsers will apply `hover` on the element that was touched last

Presumably they do so by reading `hover` as `focus`.

Therefore solution is simple!

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Non-minimum markup to show how it can be used -->
<div class="btn btn-default">
  <a href="link-1">LINK 1</a>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="show_or_hide_by_id('dropdown-2')">
  (non)LINK 2
</button>
<div id="dropdown-2">
  <div class="btn btn-default">
    <a href="link-2-1">LINK 2.1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-default">
    <a href="link-2-2">LINK 2.2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
Bootstrap classes `btn` and `btn-default` are used here. **These are NOT necessary**. Also `show_or_hide_by_id()` is my JS function that changes `display` property's value to `none`, if the value is currently `block`, otherwise it changes it to `block`.

**CSS**

```css
div,
button {
  color: #666;
}
a {
 color: inherit;
}
a:hover,
button:hover { // first :hover
  color: #66f;
}
button:focus { // second :focus
  color: inherit;
}
#dropdown-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

**NOTE:**
All other CSS selectors' order does not matter, but it is important to have `button: focus` AFTER `button: hover`.

***end ORIGINAL POST***

Answer (score 3):

Touchscreens can't detect "hovering". Touching the screen counts as clicking, not hovering.

Most mobile browsers will apply `:hover` style on the element that was touched last. This allows dropdown menus to be used even on mobile. There's not much you can do to prevent this. I tested selecting `:hover:not(:active):not(:focus)` and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When your button is released, it remains active (focused).

To solve it, you can do:

```
.subscribe_button:active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: `:active` and `:focus` are two different things, but neither seem to work (at least, on Chrome's mobile emulator)

Answer (score 0):

This solution sets a background-color to the initial button color with the pseudo class `focus`:

```
button {
    background-color: red;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: red;
}

button:active {
    background-color: #d70000;
}
```

This works fine on mobile devices but on a desktop device the clicked button still has the `hover` and `focus` attribut set: Hovering the clicked button would result in not have any feedback (until an other element gets the focus).

Answer (score 0):

Only make the `hover` pseudo class available for desktop devices with a mouse:

```
/* for mouse devices */
@media (hover: hover), (-moz-touch-enabled: 0), (pointer:fine) {
    button:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

button:active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

This is why:

> Note: The :hover pseudo-class is problematic on touchscreens.
> Depending on the browser, the :hover pseudo-class might never match,
> match only for a moment after touching an element, **or continue to
> match even after the user has stopped touching and until the user
> touches another element**.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover